# Jenkins behind Apache Web Server

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've spent the entire day trying to work out what my mod_rewrite rules should be for putting Jenkins behind Apache.

I want to be able to access Jenkins via *ci.mydomain.com* . My current config allows me to access Jenkins however some resources are not loaded (for example the background image, and the *New Job Link*)

The problem is that an extra jenkins is being put into the URL. ie http://mydomain.com/jenkins/view/All/newJob where it should read http://mydomain.com/view/All/newJob

my config is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com\.$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/jenkins/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://mydomain.co/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Could somebody please correct the error of my ways...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/jenkins/(.*)$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^jenkins/(.*)$ http://mydomain.co/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: my answer is based on yours but has a couple of changes. The second line caused mydomain.com/static/b56ff177/scripts/hudson-behavior.js to become http://mydomain.com/mydomain.com/static/b56ff177/scripts/hudson-behavior.js